# Dropdownlist is not changing the gridview data after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

My issue, I have two stored procs, one is calling data to fill the dropdown list, and another that fills my gridview. What I need is when I select an item from the dropdown list, the page should refresh and update the gridview with the new data. But the issue I am having is, after each postback the same data and page appears, so its not pulling new data... I have a hardcoded value for my select value but I also need to take this out so that when the users pick an item then it automatically updates...

#### ASPX

```
namespace WorkStationUITarget
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //public static int CountLabel = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Refreshdata(225);
                BindDropDownList();



            }
        }

        private void BindDropDownList()
        {
            BizManager mgr = new BizManager();


            DropDownList1.DataSource =
            mgr.GetItemSeriesMaster(); //.DefaultView.RowFilter("ID = 201"); //how to filter data
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DESCRIPTION"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID"; // the id of the items displayed
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

         }


        public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //refreshes to the new table on drop selection
        }
        public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct)
        {
            BizManager biz = new BizManager();


            GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(new DateTime(2016, 6, 10, 6, 0, 0)
                , new DateTime(2016, 6, 10, 13, 59, 59)
                , selectedProduct).DefaultView;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            //rebind the data

        }
```

#### bizmanager class

```
 public class BizManager
    {


        public string Shiftstart { get; set; }

        public string Shiftend { get; set; }

        public string Itemseriesmaster { get; set; }

        public string SeriesMasterId { get; set; }




        public DataTable GetPacktstatisticsForShift(DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd, int seriesMasterId)
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                dmgr.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductionKey"]);
                DataSet dset = dmgr.TargetQuantites(seriesMasterId, shiftStart, shiftEnd);
                return CreatePackingStats(dset);

            }
        }

        public DataTable GetItemSeriesMaster()
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                dmgr.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductionKey"]);
                DataSet dset = dmgr.getworkstationnames();//IManSeriesList();
                return dset.Tables[0];

            }
        }

        public DataTable CreatePackingStats(DataSet dset)
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                DataTable target = dset.Tables[0];

                DataTable actual = dset.Tables[1];

                DataColumn[] cols = new DataColumn[1];
                cols[0] = actual.Columns["Hour"];
                actual.PrimaryKey = cols;

                DataTable final = new DataTable();



                // Create table columns
                foreach (DataColumn col in target.Columns)
                {
                    final.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType));
                    if (col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                    {
                        // Add an equivilant actual column
                        string newColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace("Target", "Actual");
                        final.Columns.Add(newColumnName, col.DataType);
                    }
                }
                //// Add rows to new table
                foreach (DataRow row in target.Rows)
                {
                    string key = row["Hour"].ToString();

                    DataRow newRow = final.Rows.Add();
                    // Store column value
                    foreach (DataColumn col in final.Columns)
                    {


                        if (col.ColumnName.Contains("HOUR") || col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                        {
                            newRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Find actual data
                            DataColumn actColumn = actual.Columns[col.ColumnName] as DataColumn;
                            if (actColumn == null)
                            {
                                newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString()))
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                return final;



            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### Datamanager class

```
namespace WorkStationUITarget.Data
{
    public partial class DataManager : DataLayer
    {

        public DataSet TargetQuantites(int itemSeriesMasterId, DateTime shiftstart, DateTime shiftend)
        {
            object[] args = new object[3] { itemSeriesMasterId, shiftstart, shiftend };
            return CallSp(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), args) as DataSet;
        } // CALLS A STORED PROC

        public DataSet getworkstationnames() //IManSeriesList() //CHANGE BACK FOR OTHER USP
        {
            object[] args = new object[] {} ;
            return CallSp(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), args) as DataSet; 
        }
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WorkStationUITarget.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>


         body {
             font-family: Arial;
             color: white;
         }

        .split {
            height: 100%;

            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        .left {
            left: 0;
            background-color: #110;
            width: 30%;

            text-align: center;
        }


        .right {
            right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            width: 70%;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align: center;
        }

        .centered img {
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="split left">
    <div class="center">

        <h1 style="color: red; font-weight: bold; position: static; text-align: center; padding-top: 25px "> TOTAL QUANTITY PACKED


            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="1"  Width="100%" Height="100%" Font-Size="250px" style="position: static; text-align: center; padding-top: 280px; "></asp:Label>

            <img src="Logo/siemensblack1.png"   style="position: static;  top: 110px;  padding-top: 300px";  />
        </div>

        <div class="body-container;">
    </div>
</div>
   <form runat="server">
<div class="split right">
    <div class="center">


        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" align="centered"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged"   >
            <asp:ListItem Value="214">214</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="225">225</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>


        <h1 style="color: red; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">CELL TARGETS & ACTUAL FIGURES</h1>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="5px" CellPadding="25" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="24px" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99"/>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="white" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black"/>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"/>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black"/>
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2"/>
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384"/>
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3"/>
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357"/>


        </asp:GridView>

        <div class="w3-container">
            <div class="center">
                <style>
                    div { padding: 30px 10px 15px; }

                    .newStyle1 {
                        color: #FF0000;
                        font-size: 86px;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>

            <img src="Logo/siemenswhite1.png" style="padding-left: 70px; padding-top: 13px; position: static; text-align: center;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I assume it must be something to do with the aspx code behind page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the selected product-ID and pass it to `Refreshdata`:

```
public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int productId;
    if(int.TryParse(Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue, out productId))
        Refreshdata(productId);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, recently i have changed my code to add the datetime today etc... on refreshing my page, the dropdown reverts back to the hardcoded value, do you know how i can remove the hardcoded value and pass in a default or something?   public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime shiftStart = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime shiftEnd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);
            int productId;
            if (int.TryParse(Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue, out productId))
      Refreshdata(productId, shiftStart, shiftEnd);