# Refreshing a page to display statistics for time now

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ι have a page that brings back gridview with data from a specific date and time (hardcoded)

Ηow can Ι change this so that the data shows todays statistics? I also want it to start at specific times and then reset after a given time, eg 6am-2pm - 2pm-10pm - 10pm - 6am.

```
 public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct)
        {
            BizManager biz = new BizManager();


            GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(new DateTime(2016, 6, 10, 6, 0, 0)
                , new DateTime(2016, 6, 10, 13, 59, 59)
                , selectedProduct).DefaultView;
            GridView1.DataBind();

 public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int productId;
                if(int.TryParse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, out productId))
                    Refreshdata(productId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add more parameters to the method and pass them:

```
public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
{
    BizManager biz = new BizManager();

    GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(
          shiftStart
        , shiftEnd
        , selectedProduct).DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
} 

public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime shiftStart = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime shiftEnd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);
    int productId;
        if(int.TryParse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, out productId))
            Refreshdata(productId, shiftStart, shiftEnd);
}
```

Comment: Thats not working :( It says there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'selectedproduct of default.refreshdata(int,datetime,datetime) this is showing in my page load when i call Refreshdata method.

Comment: @DomBolton: then you have to pass in `Page_Load` also the `shiftStart` and `shiftEnd` parameters, in the same way i've shown in `Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry about the dumb questions but what exactly do i need to put in the page load ? # protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Refreshdata();
                BindDropDownList();

                
                
            }
        }

Comment: I have them two methods, refreshdata(214) and binddropdownlist

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491664/dropdownlist-is-not-changing-the-gridview-data-after-postback/50491755#50491755) you showed your `Page_Load` with a hard coded product-id 255. If that's ok for you the code would be: `Refreshdata(225, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));` and the rest of `Page_Load`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, once again :)

Comment: Hi, Do you know how i can make the data reset after certain periods, like 6am - 2pm reset to 0-  2pm - 10pm set to 0 - 10pm-6am reset to zero?

Comment: @DomBolton: Open a new question, i dont understand